# Android App crashes when not connected to Internet or WIFI otherwise, it is fine

Tags: android, crash

My application works fine when there is an internet connection, but if it doesn't it won't even launch, crashes and shuts the app down.

Is there a way I can ask user to connect to the internet at the program launch, else shut down the app?

Comment: You can but your app shouldn't crash if there is no network. Beside some more information we can't really help..

Comment: I thouight it would be a general issue, sorry will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create an start activity which checks for existing internet connection and continues immediatly to the main activity if internet is available.
This start activity may also have some instructions to the user and should also have a button to jump to the wifi settings making it easier for the user to activate internet if he wants to.

But even when internet is availabe at the time of start - it might get lost while the user is moving.
So your app should not crash at any time but always catch such connections errors

Comment: very theoratical answer